# Propagating extra fields/New fields distributed tracing solution for SpringCloud. configuring in BootClass

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

Added dependency for cloud sleuth and zipkin dependency of version below in pom.xml

```
Pom.xml 

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
----------------------
<spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
--------------------------------------
```

Simple spring boot class. Should i add filter to set new fields?

```
java class:

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application{

@Autowired
    static Tracing tracing;
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        tracing.newBuilder().propagationFactory(
                  ExtraFieldPropagation.newFactory(B3Propagation.FACTORY, "TENENT-ID")
                  );
           ExtraFieldPropagation.set("TENENT-ID", "USA");

  logger.info("Tenent ID :- "+"TENENT-ID  "+ExtraFieldPropagation.get("TENENT-ID"));
SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

}
-----

logback-spring.xml

<property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN"
        value="%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(--TenentID for UserMS-- %X{X-B3-TENENT-ID:-}) %clr(---%X{TENENT-ID:-}) %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}" />
```

resultant LOG is no showing the newly added property :

```
Config  : Hello from service1. Calling service2
2019-09-30 19:18:32.120 DEBUG [userms,,,] 30008 --TenentID for UserMS--  --- --- [ender@19fff202}] o.s.c.s.z.s.ZipkinRestTemplateWrapper    : HTTP POST http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans
```

[image]
does something i am missing ..?

Comment: @adriancole
adriancole     help me if you find some time.

Comment: Brixton is long not supported. You'll need to upgrade to Greenwich and boot 2.1.8

Comment: @spencergibb i upgraded to  Greenwich and 
  ```
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
  ```
but Log is still not showing up

Comment: Greenwich.SR3 and boot 2.1.8 are the latest

Comment: @spencergibb thanks for the replay , i updated the exact versions , But still i am not able to see in Logger , I added screenshot , Can please have a look  , I have added that properties in logback-spring.xml as well